# How to use cloudfront for a DNS Failover

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

We were setting up a aws infrastructure with DNS Route53 failover like mentioned in this aws link.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/create-a-backup-website-using-route-53-dns-failover-and-s3-website-hosting/

So we have primary ELB and secondary ELB.

But we will lose the functionality if we point primary to cloudfront, because of losing healthcheck functionality.
So is there a solution if we wants to use cloudfront ? Or do we need to choose any other solution like HAProxy ?

Answer (score 1):

CloudFront targets can't be health-checked by Route 53 because "unhealthy" isn't a situation that is supposed to occur in this context.

CloudFront uses Route 53, itself, and the IP addresses returned for a given query will be the addresses of edge nodes that are both (a) closest/most optimum for a given viewer and (b) healthy.  CloudFront -- like Route 53 -- is a massive, global, distributed, fault-tolerant system.

[Optimizing High Availability with CloudFront Origin Failover](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/high_availability_origin_failover.html) explains how CloudFront can be configured to send all cache-miss requests to a primary origin server (load balancer in your case) and to retry only the failed requests using a secondary origin server.  You can specify which types of failures cause a retry and which do not (e.g. you might want to retry any failure except for 404 errors).